# Can you do a two sided belongs_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this possible?

```
class CarActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inspection
end
class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car_activity # instead of using a has_one here
end
```

The goals are:

- Make inspecting DB records easier: seeing at the table column (using the hirb gem) if an inspection has an associated car_activity, without looping over the inspections and checking the object's car_activity reference.
- Make queries easier: getting all inspections without an associated car_activity (ie. set to `nil`) could be done in a simple direct query for the inspections table, without having to go via querying (or joining in) the car_activities table.

Update: Perhaps there is a better way to achieve these goals?

Comment: That's not how database (or Rails) work. It means that you now need an additional update query for every record creation, it means it's extremely easy for your database to wind up in an inconsistent state, and it means that you cannot use foreign key constraints to enforce relational integrity. It breaks ACID and it denormalizes your database, which *can* be important, if you understand why you're doing it, but this questions speaks to a lack of understanding in how relational databases work.

Comment: @meagar Yes, you would need an additional update query when creating inspections, but is that so hard to do? This is putting an additional constraint on the database, so I'm not so sure it breaks relational integrity..? How exactly do you mean it breaks any of the ACID properties (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability)? It denormalizes the DB in the sense it introduces some redundancy, but unless there is a better way to achieve the two goals mentioned (?), I am willing to do that.

Comment: The better way is the bog standard universally accepted way: A single foreign key in one or the other table, and a `belong_to/has_one` in Rails.

Comment: @meagar Then how would you acheive the two stated goals using that approach then?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using Polymorphic?

```
class CarActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inspection
end
class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to : car_activity, polymorphic: true
end
```

[Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) states “with polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association”.

Comment: That's a complete misuse of polymorphic associations, they have no applicability here.

Comment: @meagar fair enough.